# VBA code in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

Im Monching, Is there somebody who can help me to solve my excel vbs code because I'm new to this work.
the "copy to the database have some problem in which is cannot solved. I need that the entry is dependent in the 2 cbo.

When I put my data in the userform, the data was overwrite the other data in the same cell.
I need that the amount to be input in the userform are dependent in the cboMembers and cboMonth. if I choose one of the member and the month, I need the entry are specific to the cell of the members and the month.

```
Private Sub cboMembers_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub cboMonth_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
' Clear the form
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
            ctl.Value = ""
        ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
            ctl.Value = False
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
If OptionButton1 Then Set ws = Worksheets("Share")
If OptionButton2 Then Set ws = Worksheets("Salary")
If OptionButton3 Then Set ws = Worksheets("Emer")
If OptionButton4 Then Set ws = Worksheets("Bday")
If OptionButton5 Then Set ws = Worksheets("Educ")

On Error Resume Next

iRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", Range("B2"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
On Error GoTo 0
iRow = iRow + 0

' Check user input
    If Me.cboMembers.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a Members.", vbExclamation, "UserForm1"
        Me.cboMembers.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Me.cboMonth.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a Month.", vbExclamation, "UserForm1"
        Me.cboMonth.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Me.txtAmountPaid.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter an Amount.", vbExclamation, "UserForm1"
        Me.txtAmountPaid.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(Me.txtAmountPaid.Value) Then
        MsgBox "The Amount box must contain a number.", vbExclamation, "UserForm1"
        Me.txtAmountPaid.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

'copy the data to the database
    RowCount = Worksheets("Share").Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        With Worksheets("Share").Range("B2")
        .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.cboMembers.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.cboMonth.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.txtAmountPaid.Value
        End With

'clear the data
Me.cboMembers.Value = ""
Me.cboMonth.Value = ""
Me.txtAmountPaid.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton1.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton2.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton3.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton4.Value = ""
Me.OptionButton5.Value = ""
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cmonth As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("LookUpEntry")

For Each cmonth In ws.Range("Month")
    With Me.cboMonth
        .AddItem cmonth.Value
    End With
Next cmonth

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Please Use the Close Button!"
End If
End Sub
```

here is my useform, the members and the month are there in the form. when i choose the members and the corresponding month, I want the value in the amount paid write in the specific cell. if I choose the share, the value of the amount paid is automatically enter in the share sheet. if i choose Member in the A4 and the month in F1, the value of the amount paid would be in the F4. I need the code for that.

my Form

A2 to A234 is my members

B1 to M1 is my Month

Comment: unclear what you're asking.
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to first make the title more meaningful (you have nothing but tag info in it, which doesn't belong there at all, and it says nothing about the question you're asking), and then to explain what exactly your question is? Posting a big block of code (which is `VBA`, by the way, not `VBS`) isn't really enough. I have no idea what the actual question is here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may lie in this section of code:

```
With Worksheets("Share").Range("B2")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.cboMembers.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.cboMonth.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.txtAmountPaid.Value
End With
```

you are copying the value from `cboMembers` into cell `(rowCount + 2, 2)`. You then copy the value of `cboMonth` into the same cell - overwriting the value from `cboMembers` that had previously been put there.

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do but this code may work better:

```
With Worksheets("Share").Range("B2")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.cboMembers.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.cboMonth.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.txtAmountPaid.Value
End With
```